# Using Mahout from JRuby raises "missing class or uppercase package name" for some classes

Tags: java, jruby, mahout

I'm attempting to use Mahout in JRuby by requiring the following three JAR files from the [latest stable Mahout distribution](http://apache.cs.utah.edu/mahout/0.9/).

- mahout-core-0.9.jar
- mahout-integration-0.9.jar
- mahout-math-0.9.jar

Some of the classes I'm trying to use work fine, but some in particular aren't loading. Instead I get exceptions like this one:

```
NameError: missing class or uppercase package name (`org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender')
  get_proxy_or_package_under_package at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:54
                      method_missing at file:/Users/bloudermilk/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.10/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/java_package_module_template.rb:14
                              (root) at _test.rb:9
```

I'm sure that the class exists in the package, as [it is mentioned in the docs](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/recommender/GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender.html). In fact I can also decompress the `mahout-core` JAR and see the respective `.class` file in there.

I uploaded a test repo to GitHub here: https://gist.github.com/bloudermilk/8832036

I don't have any Java experience so it seems likely I'm missing something obvious. Why isn't JRuby able to find this class? How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried this, I got an error like:

```
Java::OrgApacheMahoutCfTasteImplRecommender::GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender
NameError: cannot link Java class org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender, probable missing dependency:
```

My guess is that you don't have something on your classpath. I took the "big hammer" approach to get everything on the classpath and was able to get it to work:

```
Dir['./mahout/*jar'].each {|f| require f}
Dir['./mahout/lib/*jar'].each {|f| require f}
Java::OrgApacheMahoutCfTasteImplRecommender::GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender
```

Comment: Indeed you were right, missing dependency. I added [JBundler](https://github.com/mkristian/jbundler) to the project and now it's working great. I wonder why I didn't get as helpful of an error as you though o_O